# AppEngine Standard: how to dispatch based on service name and version?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

Is there a way via the dispatch.yaml file to dispatch a request to the right service based on the version and the service name ?

I mean, I have this request:
https://va4-0-0-dot-api-acceptance-dot-myapp.appspot.com/auth/user

It is sent by my `api-acceptance` service but I'd like it to go to my `auth-acceptance` service.

I have written in my dispatch those rules, but it does not work...

```
- url: "va4-0-0.myapp.appspot.com/auth/*"
  service: auth-acceptance
- url: "api-acceptance.myapp.appspot.com/auth/*"
  service: auth-acceptance
```

Comment: Try `- url: "va4-0-0.api-acceptance.myapp.appspot.com/auth/*`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing), the URL pattern that you're using:

`https://[VERSION_ID]-dot-[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`

will be bypassed by the dispatch.yaml file, so it's not possible to reroute the request this way.

Using the above pattern you are already being very specific to which service and version you want to route the request.

So either you change the URL to `https://[VERSION_ID]-dot-auth-acceptance-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/auth/user` or use a [default routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#default_routing) which can later be [overriden by a dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_with_a_dispatch_file).